# How to run PowerShell scripts from Kotlin?

Tags: powershell, kotlin

How can I run a Powershell script using Kotlin?

I tried to port some Java code I found on StackOverflow, but I couldn't get it to work. I also tried the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe [path to file]")
```

but that didn't work either.

What is the simplest way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add "-File" argument, e.g. script should be like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe -File d:\\my-script.ps1")
```

Please see [PowerShell documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6).