# Running powershell scripts in Kotlin without creating a file

Tags: powershell, kotlin, runtime.exec

So I learned how to run a ps1 file from kotlin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684385/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-kotlin), but the only purpose I have for that file is to run the commands, then delete itself. Is there any way to remove the hassle of creating a file that later will just be deleted?

I have a one lined string of commands, each separated by a semicolon.

### Edit

Some people asked for the powershell code, here it is: 
(I split it into lines, but really it's just one line)
The dollar signs without backslashes in front of them are references to variables in kotlin.

```
"\$ComObj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; " +
"\$ShortCut = \$ComObj.CreateShortcut(\"\$Env:${shortcut.absolutePath}\"); " +
"\$ShortCut.TargetPath = \"%windir%\\system32\\cmd.exe\"; " +
"\$ShortCut.Description = \"${f.nameWithoutExtension}\"; " +
"\$ShortCut.Arguments = \"/c \"\"start $url\"\"\"; " +
"\$ShortCut.FullName; \$ShortCut.WindowStyle = 7; " +
"\$ShortCut.IconLocation = \"$iconpath\"; " +
"\$ShortCut.Save(); " +
"Remove-Item \"${createPs.absolutePath}\"; "
```

(The code is written to a file before being run, something that I dont want)

Comment: In order to offer some assistance can you share what you have scripted?

Comment: @thomschumacher I added the powershell code just now

Comment: what is the file you trying to prevent ? the snippet?

Comment: @thomschumacher The code is written to a file

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe -File d:\\scriptSnippetAbove.ps1")  is this how you running it … where ScriptSnippetAbove.ps1 is the code above?

Comment: @thomschumacher Yes sir

Comment: if you can put your script in a variable and the variable will expand upon calling powershell you could do it this way Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe -command '\$yourvariable'")  Of course you'll need to experiment with the right escape chars to get quotes around the command you want to run.

Comment: @thomschumacher Thanks a lot. I will test this tomorrow (It's kinda late in Norway) . You could enter this as an answer and i'll add the green correct thing it if it works tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your script in a variable and the variable will expand upon calling PowerShell you could do it this way

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe -command '\$yourvariable'")`

Of course you'll need to experiment with the right escape chars to get quotes around the command you want to run.

I've had the most success with this type of thing by first running it in CMD.exe and figuring out the proper syntax. Then take it to your program.  That way you'll know you get the PowerShell syntax down correctly first.  From what I understand parsing for PowerShell is all done after the engine starts up.  So when you call PowerShell in this manner you have to get the syntax just right.